# Exportar datos de excel a sql

Tags: sql-server, excel

Como se puede hacer para exportar una tabla de excel a una tabla de SQL Server y que además cada vez que alguien agregue, edite o elimine un valor de la tabla de excel ese mismo valor se elimine de la tabla de sql?

Ya pude exportar los valores de una tabla a sql pero si agrego, edito o elimino algo de excel no pasa nada en la tabla de sql, también intenté hacerlo con openrowset pero me lanzaba este error:

cannot create an instance of ole db provider "microsoft.ace.oledb.16.0" for linked server

Y yo estaba haciendo algo como esto:

```
    INSERT INTO User (turno,num_empleado,num_asociado,apellido1,apellido2,nombre,cedula,posicion,jefe,usuario)
    SELECT --de los campos de excel
a.turno,a.num_empleado,a.num_asociado,a.apellido1,a.apellido2,a.nombre,a.cedula,a.posicion,a.jefe,a.usuario
    FROM 
    OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0','Excel 16.0;Database=C:\Users\MiUsuario\Desktop\ExcelImport.xls','SELECT * FROM [Libro$]')AS a;
```

Entonces como podría hacer para que me funcione?

Comment: No entiendo porque quieres hacerlo de esa manera, pero para este caso tendrías que hacerle un truncate a la tabla de tu base de datos antes de insertar los datos del excel. Así siempre tendrás en BD los datos tal cual estén en el excel. Es la forma mas directa de hacerlo por querys.

Comment: EN mi caso, siento no poder contribuir, pero si estoy muy interesado y desesperado por realizar la misma acción, POR FAVOR, podrías exponer toda la rutina, precisamente necesito hacer lo mismo, tener permanentemente vinculada una o varias hojas de excel con SQL Server, pero no lo consigo.... Muchas gracias por anticipado, por vuestra ayuda. Y quedo a vuestra disposición por si en algún momento puedo contribuir en algo... Saludos.
Antonio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal muy buenas tardes yo lo ejecuto con este:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\CNH\CNH_DGM_VHP.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
'select * from [CNH_DGM_VHP_02$]')
```

importante, que si tu sistema es de 64 bits, el office debe estar en 64 bits e instalar el AccessDatabaseEngine_X64

no tienes que tener ningún problema, ahora si crees tener algún problema al hacerlo con código puedes hacer un DTS o bien un ETL.

también puedes hacer un linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server=OrderValues_EXCEL64,
@srvproduct='Whatever',
@provider= 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
@datasrc= 'c:\CNH\CasosdeUso.xlsx',
@provstr= 'Excel 12.0;'
```

Comment: driver ms https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734